# Particle system affects photo scanned texture in Eevee

Tags: materials, particles

I tried using a particle system on an object in Eevee and when it's visible, it affects the photo scanned material, both in the viewport and in the final render. The material becomes a solid color that changes every frame and the material isn't smooth anymore.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine this, and visualize it in my head, based on your description. I'm failing miserably. Could you add some screen shots, or even your .Blend file? That might help for understanding.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ar5h0snaGYGUHwD6SbBqiPxuICcjnoVp/view?usp=sharing